# Chain rule application to find second partials

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$x = 2r-s$, $y= r + 2s$, $V = f(x,y)$. Find $\frac {\partial^2 V}{\partial y \partial x}$ in terms of derivatives of $V$ with respect to $r$ and $s$.

My work so far:

$$\frac {\partial x}{\partial r} = 2, \quad \frac {\partial x}{\partial s} = -1, \quad \frac {\partial y}{\partial r} = 1, \quad \frac {\partial y}{\partial s} = 2.$$

The chain rule gives: $\frac {\partial V}{\partial r} = \frac {\partial V}{\partial x} \frac {\partial x}{\partial r} + \frac {\partial V}{\partial y} \frac {\partial y}{\partial r} = 2 \frac {\partial V}{\partial x} + \frac {\partial V}{\partial y}$, and similarly, $\frac {\partial V}{\partial s} = \frac {\partial V}{\partial x} \frac {\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac {\partial V}{\partial y} \frac {\partial y}{\partial s} = -\frac {\partial V}{\partial x} + 2 \frac {\partial V}{\partial y}$

I can compute $\frac {\partial ^2 V}{\partial r^2}$ and $\frac {\partial ^2 V}{\partial s^2}$ using another application of the chain rule by setting $g = \frac {\partial V}{\partial x}$ and $h = \frac {\partial V}{\partial y}$ but I am not sure how to express the partial derivatives of $V$ with respect to $y$ and $x$.

Comment: The specification for $ \ V \ $ doesn't say anything about what the form of $ \ f(x,y) \ $ is.  So you would just leave those partial derivatives as $ \ \frac{ \partial V}{\partial x} \ $ or $ \ \frac{ \partial f}{\partial x} \ , $ for example.  The specification in this problem is generic for $ \ V \ $ or $ \ f \ $ , so you won't be able to develop the expression for the partial derivatives any further.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting $r$ and $s$ in terms of $x$ and $y$. Then use the definition of the chain rule $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial s} \frac{\partial s}{\partial x} .$$ And so on for $\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial y \partial x}$.

Note that you can not compute $\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}$ or $\frac{\partial V}{\partial s}$ explicitly, since $V$ is not given explicitly.